# Get TeamCity build link having `type` and `number`

Tags: api, http, teamcity

The web UI link to a particular build looks like

```
https://teamcity/viewLog.html?buildId=585183&buildTypeId=Devops_Test
```

The number of this build is `24`. I want to construct a link pointing/redirecting to this page, having only the `buildTypeId` and number (`Devops_Test` and `24` in this case).

I can get the URL of this build using the REST API.

```
https://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:Devops_Test,number:24
```

and copy/paste teh `webUrl` attribute from the response to reach desired page. Is there way to reach target the page without this copy/paste?

Comment: There's a problem with build number: it is not guaranteed to be unique, so one can eventually get several builds when filtering by build number

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier, you can restrict the fields that come back in the response from TeamCity.

The URL https://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:Devops_Test,count:1,number:24&fields=build(webUrl) will return just the value in either XML or JSON depending on the HTTP-ACCEPT header that was sent to the server with the request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<builds>
  <build webUrl="https://teamcity/viewLog.html?buildId=585183&buildTypeId=Devops_Test"/>
</builds>
```

or

```
{
  "build": [
    {
      "webUrl": "http://teamcity/viewLog.html?buildId=585183&buildTypeId=Devops_Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, calling this from the browser will not automatically link you through to that page. Unless you are calling the API via code, you are always going to have to copy and paste the value from the response in order to visit the url.

If you require help writing a script to calling the API, extract the url and then redirect to it - please let me know.

TeamCity Documentation - [Full and Partial responses](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-FullandPartialResponses)

Hope this helps.